# Azure Devops Services Pipeline build fails. Builds successfully through Visual Studio and the msbuild command prompt

Tags: azure-devops

I have solution with 2 projects both targeting .Net Framework 4. The solution builds successfully in Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 as well as the msbuild command line.

However, when it builds in Azure DevOps Pipeline with Agent Specification vs2015-win2012r2 the first project fails with the following errors. The NuGet restore step shows it successfully installed the NuGet EntityFramework 5.0 package.

```
The type or namespace name 'Infrastructure' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'DbModelBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

When I change the Agent Specification to vs2017-win2016 the first project builds without error but the second project fails with the following errors:

```
The type or namespace name 'Description' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Http' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I do have the NuGet package Microsoft.Asp.Net.WebApi.Core.4.0.20710.0 referenced in the csproj file which contains the System.Web.Http.dll.

---

I have turned the debug option on. Here are links to the NuGet Restore Log https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lJWflXTjYTN_MQyLOnwMUr-8LKoR5JRo

and the Build Log
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ypAVWxniDLfBOBHc4gODdAoQOCQnphYg

Comment: Could you please run the pipeline again with the variable system.debug =true, then share the nuget restore log and the error build log here?

Comment: @Linda K Did you try out below solution, any good news?

Comment: No I did not try the below solution.  I was able to resolve the issue by using a self-hosted agent.

Answer (score -1):

According to your log, there is a warning message.

```
warning MSB3267: The primary reference "System.Net.Http", which is a framework assembly, could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "System.Net.Http" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Net.Http".
```

Some differences are in effect when executing a command on a local machine and when a build or release is running on an agent. If the agent is configured to run as a service on Linux, macOS, or Windows, then it is not running within an interactive logged-on session. Without an interactive logged-on session, UI interaction and other limitations exist. And there are some [troubleshooting steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops) which was provided by Microsoft.

There is a simple method that you can try to resolve the error. Delete the reference under the project's references, and then juse add it back in again.The reference was to a namespace in a local project to the solution. For some reason it was being found locally but not found when checked into and built on VSTS.